# Is "under" a appropriate preposition in this expression "region under the graph"?

Tags: meaning

> Now consider the region under the graph ABDE, which is bounded by
>   the x-axis, between the points x = 2 and x = 4—points A and B, respectively.
>   The area of the region can be found by adding the area of the square ABCE
>   and the right-angled triangle ECD, which is 2 × 2 + (1/2) × 2 × 2 = 6.

[image]

Usually this expression "area under ED" is being used more commonly.

Is "under" a appropriate preposition in this expression "region under the graph"?

Another description in that book might be much more better (just for comparison, I have no question about this part)

> the area enclosed by the graph of the probability density function
>   and the x-axis between the points x = 11 and x = 12

[image]

Comment: Isn't the graph the entire diagram?

Comment: @nnnnnn By graph, do you mean from 0 to 5?

Comment: _Under_ is the usual term for areas bounded by curves in Cartesian coordinates. The top of the graph is `UP`, and that gives _above_ and _below_ with respect to curves. By convention, the bottom bound of an area under a curve (in the first quadrant, anyway) is the X axis.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I was thinking of the wrong definition of graph. It can mean the entire diagram (including both axes, etc.), which is what I was thinking, or it can be the points being charted which is what seems to apply here. Anyway, I agree with you that in the first example "under" seems like the wrong word when they've described the shape as "ABDE"". I think your suggestion of "area under ED" makes more sense, or "area enclosed by ABDE".

Comment: The long version isn't "much better," it's only *unnecessarily wordier*.  "Area under the curve" is fine.